# How to moq an HttpContext for a method the implements IHttpHandler's ProcessRequest in .NET framework (not core)?

Tags: c#, .net, moq, httpcontext, .net-4.7.1

I have a class that implements `IHttpHandler` interface in **.NET 4.7.1.**
The class implements `ProcessRequest` which accepts an `HttpContext` instance.

I am trying to create a test for `ProcessRequest` using **Moq.** Moq allows me to create a mock for `httpContextBase` but not `HttpContext`.

```
Mock<HttpContext> mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
```

Run time error:

> Type to mock (HttpContext) must be an interface, a delegate, or a
> non-sealed, non-static class.

If I mock `HttpContextBase`, eventually calling the method and passing it will give an error:

> Cannot convert from 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' to
> 'System.Web.HttpContext'

Is there a way to mock `HttpContext`? I can't modify the class or the method as it's not my code.

Comment: Could you please share us with the to-be-tested code as well?

Comment: Can't you simply create an `HttpContext` via [that constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1#system-web-httpcontext-ctor(system-web-httprequest-system-web-httpresponse)) which anticipates an `HttpRequest`  and an `HttpResponse` objects?